# Microservices master/slave pattern

Tags: apache-zookeeper, microservices

There are scenario where you want to run a cluster of microservices in High-Availability but you would like just one of them to execute a specific operation (consuming from a queue, polling a database)

What are the best practices with relation to this use case? Should one use Zookeeper as a registry, or are there other suitable technologies?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of technologies for service registration and discovery. Please see if the following articles help:

1. [StackShare's comparison of Consul vs. ZooKeeper vs. Eureka](https://stackshare.io/stackups/consul-vs-eureka-vs-zookeeper)
2. [A nice paper for service-discovery and guide on how to make the choice](http://daviddawson.me/getting/started/with/microservices/2015/06/10/service-discovery-overview.html)

Comment: We probably would go with Consul